# Choose a (very) lightweight web-development language/framework for a specific environment

Tags: arm

I have an ARM-based NAS box (DNS-313 by D-Link) at home as a file-server (smb, nfs, p2p). It has only 30Mb of RAM, and not so fast CPU. I want to use it as a web-server for my family: maybe for photo-gallery or home bookkeeping or maybe something else. So, my question is: what web-server/language/platform/framework would be suitable for the such device? Or just lighttpd + php is the only choice? It's just for my fun, not for "production" use, so it doesn't matter if tools will have any security issues or any other things that matters in a real world of web-development.

Answer (score 1):

If one day G-WAN is compiled on ARM that might do the job: it weights just 200 KB (with the script engine included).